# CSS for fuzzy outline around input elements

Tags: input, css, styling

The possible outline styles that I know of are shown below.

- dotted
- dashed
- solid
- double
- groove
- ridge
- inset
- outset

None of these puts an outline around an input element like shown below:
[image]
With what CSS stylling can someone style an input element like shown above?

Comment: It looks like Chrome's built in rendering for input boxes. It will be rendered differently in other browsers.

Comment: why not use divs for that matter?

Comment: @yoda: Because `div` isn't meant to be an input box...?

Comment: @BoltClock: got anything better to bypass the lack of proper support for CSS3?

Comment: Browsers like IE and Netscape really lack support for newer features like CSS3, and HTML5, and when they do support them they use different syntax. For example to make an element have rounded corners or some other fancy feature then you have to use an htc file or IE wont support it, which is just another thing to learn.

Comment: Chrome's style btw is non-standard:
`outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like a browser default behavior, but you can fake it with css3 `box-shadow`

http://jsfiddle.net/meo/BndwU/

or with your colours:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/BndwU/1/

or with bonus focus animation:
http://jsfiddle.net/meo/BndwU/2/

Comment: If this is done with the box-shadow effect then how come when you set the outline to none like this outline:none; then it removes that supposed "box-shadow"

Comment: ok then try outline: inherit. I think its the browser default outline. (for chrome or safari) Secret hint: use your browsers dom inspector and see how its done.

Comment: I would appreciate the code being posted in the answer, not just a link.

Answer (score 3):

This will only work in modern browsers that accept CSS3 properties like `box-shadow`:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #ffcc00;
    box-shadow:0 0 3px #ffcc00;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3px #ffcc00;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 3px #ffcc00;
}
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/LM6HH/)

Answer (score 2):

Using the new CSS 3 box-shadow you can put a gradient border around an input box.  First wrap it in a span with a new class that contains something like:

```
.coolio {
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 0px 24px; 
}
```

Here is a working example: [Gradient Shadow Outline Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ToddHoward/KCChW/)